# How to provide access to a user for the new region for account, contact or opportunity

Tags: configuration

There is a user-A, who needs access to a country - USA within salesforce for account, contact and opportunity. Is there any way to achieve this functionality? It had been told that the user is already provided the access to another country based on zip code in account. The similar kind of access need to provided for the USA as well. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you familiar with the standard functionality available around sharing? It sounds like your org _may_ have some kind of sharing architecture already built out, which you should review with your org's architect.

Comment: I am not clear where are you exactly facing the problems. Salesforce has some standard functionality already built for these cases. If you are unaware of such facts then you may refer to the links given below: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/create-opportunity-sharing-rules